# Why does my Python code get an "not defined" error?

Tags: python, nameerror

If the variable 'key' is returned into the decrypt function, why is it not recognized?  The error reads "NameError: global name 'key' is not defined"  Here is the code:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alphaList = list(alphabet)
text = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj"

def createKey(aList):
    key = []
    count = 0
    for letter in aList:
        if count < 24:
            key.append(aList[count + 2])
        else:
            key.append(aList[count - 24])
        count += 1
    return key

def decrypt(text):
    createKey(alphaList)
    decryptedList = []
    textList = list(text)
    for c in textList:
        if c in alphaList:
            index = alphaList.index(c)       
            decryptedList.append(key[index])    
        else:
            decryptedList.append(c)
    decryptedText = "".join(decryptedList)
    return decryptedText

print decrypt(text)
```

Comment: your createKey function returns the key, but `decrypt()` doesn't capture that return value, e.g. `key = createKey(alphaList)`.

Comment: @MarcB Sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never assign `key`:

```
createKey(alphaList)
```

Change this to:

```
key = createKey(alphaList)
```

This happens because `key` in `createKey(alphaList)` is part of the `createKey` namescope. Although you return it, you don't create that as part of the `decrypt` namescope.

Alternatively, you could use global variables, but I don't recommend this, especially because there is an easy get around by assigning `key` in `decrypt()`:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alphaList = list(alphabet)
text = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj"
key = []

def createKey(aList):
    global key
    # everything else
    # no need to return, the `global key` has been changed

def decrypt(text):
    global key
    createKey(alphaList)
    # everything else
```

References:

- [Python Name Scopes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Comment: Thanks.  But why do I need to assign key?  Shouldn't the original function return key when called?

Comment: @uncleGe You might want to read up on name scopes (I'll edit and add a link to my answer). Although it IS returning `key`, key is local to that function. You could create a global, but that's frowned upon.

Comment: Ok, I got it now, and I check out the scopes link.  Thanks!